# Rebuild Sitecore Analytics db in fresh installation

Tags: experience-analytics, mongodb, indexing

We want to replace our current MongoDB and Sitecore Analytics DB on regular intervals. We are aware that it removes ALL Analytics data.

Our plan is to setup a completely fresh Sitecore Analytics SQL db and MongoDB with regular intervals - do we need to rebuild the reporting db after doing this?

This is for Sitecore 8.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, rebuilding the reporting DB will take all the data from the collections databases (MongoDd), so as you are replacing those too, there probably isn't much merit to rebuilding the reporting database.

However, you probably should redeploy the marketing definitions when you start with a clean reporting/analytics database, otherwise the aggregation tasks will not write the correct data.